# qt app.exec() segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I have coded an application in QT. The app runs fine but on exit I get an

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

how can I solve this segmentation problem?

Comment: There's not much to work with here. If it happens on exit, it may have to do with your memory management in your destructors, such as freeing a freed pointer. I recommend using `gdb` to load the coredump and see the stack trace.

Comment: I cant figure out where the dump is ? there is no dump file in the folder the executable runs from.

Comment: There should be a core file, since your computer does tell you "core dumped".  If you don't see it, then run your program within `gdb` to begin with.

Comment: core does not get generated automatically. One needs to specify ulimit -c unlimted.

Comment: I figured out the problem . Boost asio service was running even after the app.exec() which tried to reference some pointers which were freed. When this service was quit before the main.cpp got finished , the errors were fixed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code, anyway i guess it could be something in destructors if you do something wrong there. In particular if you allocate memory with malloc/new of your basic stuff (array of integers i.e.) and so on...